# How to connect Windows XP to printer connected to Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-xp, windows-10, printer, network-shares

I can see the printer, but I get “Permission denied.” I add everyone, guest, guests, set all privileges for all and always the same: “Permission denied.”

Not only home, but professional also can’t connect.

Comment: My guess is guests are disabled and `Everyone` does not include anonymous (since at least 7); so you need to correctly authenticate to use the printer; a way to do this is to have both computers in the same workgroup, to have a username on XPhome which is known to the Pro machine, and using the same password. Another distinct possibility is SMB signing requirements.

Comment: @AntoineL The same WORKGROUP  - checked, user on xphome is passwordless, the same user on Win10 is also passwordless (user without admin). When I use Admin account with pass - credentials not enough sth. I don't understand SMB signing requirements...

Comment: Fact is, this afternoon I got the same kind of problem from a XPhome machine (unrelated, debugging another issue) and I do use passwords. I will investigate further thus, and if I find something useful then I will post back here...

Comment: @JakeGould - what else than professional could it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4eddf3ad-ac25-40f5-95d1-deef89870674/unable-to-share-windows-10-printer-with-older-windows-xp-desktop?forum=win10itpronetworking%20HERE); many thanks to [wjacsh](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/wjacsh/?ws=usercard-mini%20wjacsh):

1. You have to see the printer in explorer - so you have to log into `\\Win10MachineName` (with valid credentials)
2. Add Printer - LOCAL Printer, new Local Port : `\\Win10MachineName\sharedPrinter` (e.g `\\MyComp\HP1005`)
3. If the port is in use, find it in existing Local Ports
4. Voila!!!

If you have problem with “Printer Processor not found or invalid” - change driver; don’t use the existing driver.

**updated:**
There can be problems with credentials - if you are not logged in to `\\Win10MachineName` after reboot - the port is unavailable until you log in.

Comment: This one saved me the day. No way I would remember of adding a printer as Local, and then setting the location as a remote \\machinename\printer thing.

Thank god windows is becoming more POSIX like. These hacks are frustrating for someone who uses daily several POSIX like systems

Answer (score 1):

From XP:

Add Printer → LOCAL Printer, new Local Port

`\\Win10MachineName\sharedPrinter` (e.g `\\MyComp\HP1005`) or IP address Win10 (e.g. `\\172.16.101.84\sharedprinter`)

Answer (score 0):

Check your Windows 10 advanced sharing properties. Enable file sharing for all networks and choose the option *Enable File Sharing for Devices That Use 40- or 56-Bit Encryption* (by default it's 128-bit). Then try printing again.

Comment: The OP has already marked this as complete. His issue was with incorrect credentials

Comment: This one didn't work for me @SledgehammerPL's answer was the only way. I tried this first, and even disabling passwords, but to no effect

Answer (score -1):

This helped me. I didn´t try badongero's solution (but looks good when having "only driver files" without setup)

My actual solution:
First install printer locally. This involves running appropriate OS compatible printer drivers setup for USB connection (connecting for a while the printer).

Next make shure a connection to the server is open. Verify typing > **NET USE** in a CMD Window and if neccessary, just open in File explorer \\HostPC -write it in the direction box-, and credentials will be prompted.

Finally make the new local Port creation / assignment.

For badongero's way: First make shure an open connection to the HostPC exists. Then try the AddPrinter -> Local printer -> NewPrinterPort ...

Note: In some scenarios on rebooting PC, will not restore connection. Put a shortcut to File Explorer opening the Host machine in ..programs START folder to reset the connection everytime.